# Return outside of function gives an error but print works fine

Tags: python

Below is my code. I want to use the finalList in some other function, so  I am trying to return finalList, but I am getting an error 'return' outside function.
If I use print finalList, it is printing the result fine.

Any idea what to do?

```
import csv   
from featureVector import getStopWordList  
from preprocess import processTweet  
from featureVector import getFeatureVector  

inpTweets = csv.reader(open('sampleTweets.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='|')  
stopWords = getStopWordList('stopwords.txt')   
featureList = []   
tweets = []   
for row in inpTweets: 
    sentiment = row[0]   
    tweet = row[1]  
    processedTweet = processTweet(tweet)  
    featureVector = getFeatureVector(processedTweet)  
    featureList.extend(featureVector)
    tweets.append((featureVector, sentiment));

finalList = list(set(featureList))
```

Comment: Where is your function?

Comment: You can't return here, you have zero functions defined

Comment: Oh okay but if I want use that finalList output in some other function , what should I do

Comment: What errors are you seeing when you try to use it in another function?? Again, there are no functions here

Comment: Yup got it .. need to defined function.. that was a stupid question.. am new to Python..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I want to use the finalList in some other function

You can already do this.

```
# other code...
finalList = list(set(featureList))  # this is global

def foo():
    print(finalList)

foo()
```

---

> 'return' outside function

If you want to `return finalList`, then make a function for it.

```
def getFinalList():
    # other code...
    return list(set(featureList))
```

Option 1

```
def foo():
    final_list = getFinalList()
    print(final_list)

foo()
```

Option 2

```
def foo(final_list):
    print(final_list)

foo(getFinalList())
```